# Auto reconnect not woring in kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using kafka-0.8.1.1 version,in this version auto reconnect doesn't work via java code.
I am having property file as

```
props.put("zookeeper.connect", "zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181");
props.put("group.id", KAFKA_GROUPID);
props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "10000");
props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "200");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
```

while I start the consumer thread,it's connected to kafka server,in between thread running server loss the connection towards kafka server for  2 hours.if it reconnect kafka consumer doesn't recieve any message and also it doesn't throws any error on the flow.

How can we detect it losses connection and reconnect the consumer thread automatically.

Thanks in advance